# Can I connect a switch to a modem and router?

Tags: networking

I recently bought a 2nd ps4 so I could play bo3 with family members. Sadly with my Linksys router it refuses to allow both ps4s to use nat type open or moderate. My question is could I connect some sort of switch or hub to my modem, then use one ps4 on Wi-Fi and the other use a port on the switch? The logic behind this is that the router only allows 1 device like the ps4 to connect using the correct nat type, so by using one on Wi-Fi and the other directly connected to the modem it will allow both devices to work correctly, does this seem possible? I am planning on calling Linksys, but want some opinions first.

Comment: You are confusing the network layers. Your LAN (layer-2) has nothing to do with layer-3 (IP) or layer-4 (TCP, UDP, etc.).

Comment: "*Sadly with my Linksys router it refuses to allow both ps4s to use nat type open or moderate*" Do you have some reason to think this is an issue with your router, rather than just the nature of having just one public IP.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because you need UPnP enabled on your router. The setup you describe won't help you. You could manually assign ports to each PS4 and then forward them each on the router but nobody has time for that.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP allows you to have two or more IP addresses, you might be able to connect both Playstations directly to the modem; if the modem has only one port, it would require a switch to do this.  Added benefits to not having a router in front of your Playstation would be lower latency, and less complexity.  Detriments might include a possible recurring surcharge for each additional IP address, and less protection against network intrusions.  However, since these are gaming consoles, as opposed to general purpose computing systems, this may not be an appreciable risk.

Comment: If your ISP will assign you multiple IP addresses, then connecting a switch to your modem, and both PS4s and possibly the LinkSys' WAN port to the switch, the PS4s will not depend on the router's NAT configuration, and talk to other servers directly.  Depending on the ISP, there may be an additional cost per number of hosts, or, perhaps they already allow 3 or more directly-connected devices to have their own IP addresses.  If you don't have a switch yet, you might try connecting each PS4 directly to the modem to see if they can get online, and if they get different IPs.

Comment: If each device can connect, and get different IP addresses, it may just work without a call to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nevin for your reply, so this setup I described could work? For the people who asked, yes its my router, I rather not port forward as I'm not into networking but more into computers, so I would have to learn way too much instead of just adding some hardware. In my opinion it's easier and will save time.

Comment: You might want to instead leave a comment on my answer, so the conversation will be in context.

Comment: My answer to the questions in asked in this answer  are in comments below my original answer.